# ORA-06550 with alter statement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying this code for some test and i got this error ORA-06550

I tried to modify column with set and many things still the same result

CODE :

```
declare

cursor cur is select  comm from emp where comm is not null ;

enreg emp.comm%type;

moyene number;

somme number;

begin

open cur;
loop

fetch cur into enreg;

if emp.comm=enreg.com then

ALTER TABLE emp 

set columun 

emp.comm := enreg.com*100/emp.comm ;  

end if ;

exit when cur%notfound;

end loop;

end;
```

the expected result is to change every emp.comm with the 10% of it but i got this error

Error :

```
ORA-06550: line 12, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER" when expecting one of the following:

   ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma
   raise return select update while with 
     <<
   continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
   savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge

1. declare
2. cursor cur is select  comm from emp where comm is not null ;
3. enreg emp.comm%type;
```

Comment: To change a value in a column you have to use [UPDATE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/UPDATE.html#GUID-027A462D-379D-4E35-8611-410F3AC8FDA5) not ALTER (which changes the **structure** of a table, not the values). But the whole procedure and the loop are completely useless this can be done with one simple UPDATE statement without loops or PL/SQL. If you really want to do this in such an inefficient and slow way, use UPDATE together with `WHERE CURRENT OF` to change the "current row" of the cursor

Comment: `ALTER` modifies the table definition (column names, datatypes, etc.), not the data itself. `UPDATE` updates column values. It would appear that a good SQL tutorial would be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, you use an `UPDATE` statement to change values in a table. `ALTER TABLE` is used to change the **structure** of a table, such as by adding columns, etc. You could rewrite your code as follows:

```
declare
  cursor cur is select  comm from emp where comm is not null;
  enreg   emp.comm%type;  
  moyene  number;
  somme   number;  
begin    
  open cur;

  loop  
    fetch cur into enreg;
    exit when cur%notfound;

    if emp.comm = enreg then
      update emp 
         set emp.comm = enreg * 100 / emp.comm;  
    end if ;
  end loop;

  commit;
end;
```

Best of luck.